# How to accelerate array_t construction in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, stl, pybind11

I used C++ to call python with Pytorch.

C++ generate a vector and send to Python for neural network to inference.

But send the vector is a time consuming process.
A vector contain 500000 float consume 0.5 second turning to array_t.

Is there a faster way to transfer vector to array_t? Any help will be appreciate!

Here is the part of code:

```
int main(){
        float list[500000];
        std::vector<float> v(list, list+length);
        py::array_t<float> args = py::cast(v); //consume 0.5 second
        py::module_ nd_to_tensor = py::module_::import("inference");
        py::object result = nd_to_tensor.attr("inference")(args);
}
```

I also tried the second way as below, but it take 1.4 second in Python to make vector into tensor:

```
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<float>);
PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(vectorbind, m) {
    m.doc() = "C++ type bindings created by py11bind";
    py::bind_vector<std::vector<float>>(m, "Vector");
}

int main(){
    std::vector<float> v(list, list+length);
    py::module_ nd_to_tensor = py::module_::import("inference");
    py::object result = nd_to_tensor.attr("inference")(&v);
}
```

Here is Python code:

```
def inference():
    tensor = torch.Tensor(Vector)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

```
py::array_t<float> args = py::array_t<float>({length}, {4}, &list[0]);
```

Directly init the array_t will be the best way